# XHR doesn't follow redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a `form` which I submit via jQuery ajax with type 'POST'. Sometimes response of that ajax is 302. When it's 302 browser shows in console that it loads page from redirect but window doesn't change location. I've found that many people tried to prevent those redirects, in my case I want to opposite.
I have no idea how to solve that. After all readings about that I understand that browser should normally load page, not only in dev tools. Maybe I misunderstand it?

Comment: _“but window doesn't change location”_ – of course it doesn’t; AJAX is supposed to be a _background_ request, and handling whatever response it gets is your script’s job. Solution: _Don’t_ issue a redirect in your server-side script, but let it answer with data that tells your client-side script what to do.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for clarifying that to me. At least now I know how to solve problem.